# Attempt at decorators with multiple order python function

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, typeerror, python-decorators

I am currently working with multiple order functions in python and as an exercise wanted to try working with a function decorator. In this example, I have a simple counter and wish to use datetime to approximate the amount of time it takes for the computer to count to a certain value given the code:

```
from datetime import datetime

def elapsedTime(f):
    time1=datetime.now()
    def runFunc():
        return f()
    time2=datetime.now()
    return time2-time1

@elapsedTime
def count(n):
    out=0
    for i in range(n):
        out += 1
    return out

out, deltaT= count(50000)
print("count(50000) returns:", out)
print("elapsed time (sec): ", deltaT.total_seconds())
print("type of deltaT: ", type(deltaT))
```

Where the output I am expecting is:

```
count(50000) returns: 50000
elapsed time (sec): (calculated value)
type of deltaT:  <class 'datetime.timedelta'>
```

However, whenever I attempt to run this code I receive an error at line 17 (where I call count(50000)) stating:

```
TypeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object is not callable
```

I'm a little lost on this one and was hoping someone could point out where the error is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the decorator (`elapsedTime()`) returns is used to *replace* the decorated function. So it better be a callable object if you still expect `count()` to work.

That's because the `@decorator` syntax is really just a little syntactic sugar; whatever function you sprinkle that syntax on, the `def function_name(...):` block is executed and instead of the regular `function_name = <function object>` assignment, the decorator is called and used, as if `function_name = decorator(<function_object(>)` was called.

Your decorator, however, only timed creating your wrapper function, and didn't actually return a new function object. It returned the timedelta result of creating the wrapper function.

Put your timer *in the `runFunc()` wrapper function*, and return that wrapper (don't call it, just return it). That way, the wrapper function replaces the original `count()` function object.

Next, make sure your wrapper function can accept any arguments, passing those on to the wrapped function. I used `*args, **kwargs` to take anything thrown at it the wrapper and pass it on, untouched, to the original function:

```
def elapsedTime(f):
    def runFunc(*args, **kwargs):
        time1 = datetime.now()
        result = f(*args, **kwargs)
        time2 = datetime.now()
        return result, (time2 - time1)
    return runFunc
```

Note that I also changed what the `runFunc()` wrapper returns. It returns the result of calling the original function, *and* the time delta. Because that's what your code appears to expect.

The above now works like this:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> def elapsedTime(f):
...     def runFunc(*args, **kwargs):
...         time1 = datetime.now()
...         result = f(*args, **kwargs)
...         time2 = datetime.now()
...         return result, (time2 - time1)
...     return runFunc
...
>>> @elapsedTime
... def count(n):
...     out=0
...     for i in range(n):
...         out += 1
...     return out
...
>>> out, deltaT = count(50000)
>>> print("count(50000) returns:", out)
count(50000) returns: 50000
>>> print("elapsed time (sec): ", deltaT.total_seconds())
elapsed time (sec):  0.006237
>>> print("type of deltaT: ", type(deltaT))
type of deltaT:  <class 'datetime.timedelta'>
```